# django-admin: redirecting after object save

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an "edit" button in the detailed view for one of my Django models. This button sends the user to the admin panel.

Example for the "project" model:

```
/admin/<app_name>/project/3108/change/
```

Once the user finishes making changes and hits "Save", they are redirected back to the main admin panel.

Is it possible, instead, to send them back to the detailed view in the app?

Answer (score 0):

The ModelAdmin class has these two methods that can be overridden:

1. [response_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add)
2. [response_change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) which is the one that suits your request on the edit button

So one way to do is to return a desired url (HttpResponse) either using a hardcoded link, a reverse function or the objects [get_absolute_url](https://get_absolute_url) method.

Comment: Thanks! Based on the documentation in those links, that certainly looks like a promising avenue. One thing I forgot to mention is that I'd only like this behaviour to occur when accessing the admin panel using this special button in my app. i.e.: I wouldn't want it to ALWAYS redirect back to the app. Do you have any suggestions on which of the three options you presented would be best?

Comment: Given you have a request object you could get the next query string (?next=URL). If it's present then redirect there. Else simply proceed in default mode. This next parameter is used in the Django authentication subsystem so sticking pretty much to a well known pattern. Ref example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: Any thoughts on the solution proposed below @gagamil?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and this was my approach:

I started by overriding the change_view function in the Django admin to store the last page URL if it wasn't an admin page:

```
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    # Capture the referer URL
    referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
    # Store the referer in the session if the referer doesn't contain 'admin'
    if 'admin' not in referer:
        request.session['referer'] = referer
    # if the referer doesn't exist in the session, give it the value 'admin'
    elif 'referer' not in request.session:
        request.session['referer'] = 'admin'
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=extra_context)
```

Then, I overrode the response_change function to redirect to the saved URL if the user clicked on "Save":

```
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
    # If the method is save
    if '_save' in request.POST and request.POST['_save'] == 'Save':
        # Retrieve and remove the referer URL from the session and redirect
        referer = request.session.pop('referer')
        if referer != 'admin':
            return redirect(referer)
    return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

This solution appears to work well, but I was wondering if there could be any unexpected problems arising from this approach or if there's a "cleaner" way to accomplish the same thing. Any feedback would be appreciated!